# three scanf resulting in two and taking garbage value

Tags: c, char, scanf

Here Is code of Basic Structure , But the output is not as expected. There is three scanf function but only two is being executed. Middle one contains garbage value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };

    struct book b1,b2,b3;

    printf("Enter names , prices & no of pages of 3 books\n");
    scanf("%c%f%d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);
    scanf("%c%f%d",&b2.name,&b2.price,&b2.pages);
    scanf("%c%f%d",&b3.name,&b3.price,&b3.pages);

    printf("And this is what you entered\n");
    printf("%c%f%d",b1.name,b1.price,b1.pages);
    printf("%c%f%d",b2.name,b2.price,b2.pages);
    printf("%c%f%d",b3.name,b3.price,b3.pages);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/SKNfAS  Its only one Character

Comment: `scanf("%c%f%d"` --> `scanf(" %c%f%d"`

Comment: provide some white space before digit or float due to some buffer rule i.e `scanf("%c %d %f", bla, blaa, blaaa);`

Comment: You need to check the return value of scanf: `if (scanf("%c%f%d", &b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages) != 3) { fprintf(stderr, "Error reading b1 input.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: skip previos newline.

Comment: `scanf("%c%f%d\n")` also helps?

Comment: @SCaffrey Yes ! Thanks

Comment: @SCaffrey Input is not complete. It will continue to wait for the input of non-blank.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY hmm, I mean adding a `\n` does escapes previous newline.

Comment: It seesm like every other post on C is 'linefeed left in buffer' these days:(

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD `scanf("%c %d %f",...` will perform like OP's `scanf("%c%d%f",...`.  It is the space before `"%c"` that is needed. "Input white-space characters ... are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier" C11 spec

Comment: @SCaffrey `scanf("%c%f%d\n")` and "adding a \n does escapes previous newline" does **not** "escapes _previous_ newline".

Comment: Yeah, yeah. my fault. Mine doesn't help with **previous**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change

```
scanf("%c%f%d", &bx.name, &bx.price, &bx.pages);
```

To

```
scanf(" %c%f%d", &b1.name, &b1.price, &b1.pages);
```

After you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a '\n' is left in `stdin`, which will later be consumed by "%c". Having read a character('\n'), `scanf()` expects a floating-point number, as "%f" in the format string indicates. However, instead of getting that desired floating-point number, it meets a character, and it returns sadly. As a result, `&bx.price` and `&bx.pages` are not updated, so they remain uninitialised, giving you the garbage values.

With a leading space in `scanf()`, all whitespace characters(if any) are discarded before reading starts. Since `\n` is discarded, following reading process will(presumably) be successful.

Also, just a tip: **Always** check the return value of `scanf()`, because you'll never know that stuff users will input.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book
{
    char name;
    float price;
    int pages;
};

int main()
{
    struct book b1, b2, ..., bx;

    printf("Enter names, prices & no of pages of x books:\n");
    while (scanf(" %c%f%d", &bx.name, &bx.price, &bx.pages) != 3)
    { 
        fputs("Error reading bx. Please try again:\n", stderr);
        scanf("%*[^\n] ");
    }
    ......

    printf("And this is what you have entered:\n");
    printf("%c %f %d", bx.name, bx.price, bx.pages);
    ......

    return 0;
}
```

Example input & output:

```
Enter names, prices & no of pages of x books:
asd wedewc efcew
Error reading bx. Please try again:
a 12.34 42
And this is what you have entered:
a 12.340000 42
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf, usually, reads the characters from standard input stream, which includes your newlines as well as spaces. so try to flush all unwanted inputs left in the stdin stream before you use scanf("%c");

Also remember: do not let %c fall somewhere in the middle of the format string

Hope this could help. unfortunately you should use it before all scanf in "Your" program

```
printf("Enter names , prices & no of pages of 3 books\n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c%f%d",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);
```

You may also use a space before %c in scanf to read whitespaces.

```
scanf(" %c"....);
```

Comment: Isn't `fflush(stdin);` undefined behaviour?

Comment: @sun qingyao Yes `fflush(stdin)` is UB. C11 spec: "Ifstream points to an output stream or an update stream ...  the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered ... otherwise, the behavior is undefined.".  `stdin` is not an output stream or an update stream.  On _some_ systems, `fflush(stdin)` it empties the stream and the same code on other machine has different results.  Robust code does not use `fflush(stdin)`.